# swift generics Array<(String,Int)>

Tags: swift, generics, collections

I would to know more about this generics definition:

```
Array<(String,Int)>
```

that came from a sort function

```
Array(tmp_emotions).sorted { $0.1 > $1.1}
```

I thought it was something equivalent to [[String:Int]], but I was wrong.
Could somebody give me some detail more?

thanks

**UPDATED**

it was an array of tuple!.

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question